# When I am writing the URL in browser the URL is not working- only the admin page is ascessed . Please show me a path

Tags: python, django, cmd

The name of my project is firstproject and web application is testapp.
ERROR: Using the URLconf defined in firstproject.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
The current path, hello, didn't match any of these.
`
``

`enter code here`from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from testapp import views

```
             urlpatterns = [
             path('hello/',views.greeting),
             path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
             ]

             from django.shortcuts import render
             from django.http import HttpResponse
             def greeting(request):
             s="<h1> hello this is greeting page</h1>"
             return HttpResponse(s)
    
             INSTALLED_APPS = [
                              'testapp',
                              'django.contrib.admin',
                              'django.contrib.auth',
                              'django.contrib.contenttypes',
                              'django.contrib.sessions',
                              'django.contrib.messages',
                              'django.contrib.staticfiles',
                               ]
```

Answer (score 0):

delete 'hello/' on urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
        path('',views.greeting),
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
     ]
```